# Recent change referencing SQL stored procedure?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Environment is Mageia 5 x86_64, Python 3.4, Postgresql 9.3.20, psycopg2-2.7.1
I have a working application that calls an external sql stored procedure called search.sql with entry point "search_columns". I access it with the statement
self.cursor.callproc('search_columns', (target,))
I have moved that application to the following environment:
Mageia 6 x86_64, Python 3.5, Postgresql 9.6.6, psycopg2-2.7.3.2. I now get an error message:
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: function search_columns(unknown) does not exist

search.sql is in the same directory as other Python modules, so there seems to have been a change in how to call stored sql procedures. Can someone help please?
Thanks 
Graeme

Answer (score 0):

'Psycopg is reporting that the search_column function doesn't exist in
the server it is connecting to. It is necessary to run the 'search.sql' file into the server in installation phase, for instance using "psql -f
search.sql", after which the psycopg code will work as expected.'
Yes, it does.